# key value pairs as search parameter?

Tags: javascript, url-parameters

how can I pass somethinglike this (these objects are just simple data represenation)

```
{2: [test,test2]}
```

within the search query? With single data there is no problem because I can just use:

```
.com/search?id=2&value=test,test2
```

but what if I have two different ids with different values like:

```
{
   2: [test,test2],
   3: [test3]
}
```

How the query would look like then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `JSON.stringify()` method. And later, on the server you can parse it back with `JSON.parse()` method.

```js
const data = { 2: ['test', 'test2'], 3: ['test3'] };

const url_param = JSON.stringify(data);

...

const result = JSON.parse(url_param)
```